# Do miles progress towards the elite status get reset on American Airlines?

Tags: loyalty-programs, american-airlines

I recently retained my gold status with the American Airlines by earning 32,545 EQM's and spending $3750 EQD's. As I retained my gold status from last year, I thought I would continue further with those EQM's and EQD's which I earned for this year 2020 so that I can get to the Platinum status. But to my surprise, the progress bar has been reset to zero. So, in order to get to Platinum, I need to travel 50000 EQM's + spend $6000 EQD's instead of the difference from the last year. Is that right? Is that how the program works? If that's right all the Exec Platinum members are spending $15,000 + flying 100000 EQM's every year to retain their status?

Comment: Note that if you fly on short notice and business class, then $15000 can be as few as two flights.

Comment: But, that’s not gonna give me 100,000 miles though ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, [the AA page on elite status](https://www.aa.com/i18n/aadvantage-program/elite-status/aadvantage-elite-status.jsp) says:

> Earn EQMs, EQSs and EQDs **during the calendar year** to qualify

(bold mine)

Most frequent flyer programs are the same -- you have to fly a lot of miles during the year, every year. Air Canada's top tier requires 100k status miles. Some airlines have a lifetime award if you pass a million or more status miles, but that is independent of the year by year qualification.

Comment: Dayummm... Thanks for clarifying it. I overlooked it! Seems like I will never reach Executive Platinum for at least a few more years where I can dedicate myself to that kind of traveling! :(

Comment: Delta also rolls over excess elite qualification miles (not elite qualification segments or dollars) to the next year.  If OP earned those EQDs/EQMs on Delta, they'd start the year with 2,545 EQMs and 0 EQDs.

Answer (score 4):

> If that's right all the Exec Platinum members are spending $15,000 + flying 100000 EQM's every year to retain their status?

Yes.

The clocks resets on Jan 1 every year and you need to start accumulating from scratch every year. You maintain the top status you reached in 2019 for all of 2020, but the accrual starts at 0 on 1/1/2020. There are no carryovers.